# Synchronize threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I'm coding a program for count the "even" numbers of a vector. I enter with a number of threads that must be created to parallelize the analyzing of the vector.

The result always must be 500, but some times It changes (485, 512, 586, 410). I guess the problem is the synchronization of the threads, but I'm using the join, so I don't know why this problem persists.

SOLVED

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define VECTOR_LENGTH 1000

int vector[VECTOR_LENGTH];
int sum = 0;
int quantity_positions;

void VerifyVector(int i){
    int j = 0;
    int vector_sum = 0;

        for (j = (i * quantity_positions); j < ((i + 1) * quantity_positions); j++)
      if ((vector[j] % 2) == 0)
        vector_sum++;
    //printf("Thread num %d sum value: %d\n", i, vector_sum);
        pthread_exit(vector_sum);
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
  int i, j;
  int threads = 0;
  int rest = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < VECTOR_LENGTH; i++)
    vector[i] = i;

  threads = atoi(argv[1]);

  if (threads <= 0)
    threads = 1;

  int threads_result[threads];

  pthread_t threads_id[threads];

  quantity_positions = VECTOR_LENGTH / threads;

  if ((quantity_positions * threads) != VECTOR_LENGTH)
    rest = VECTOR_LENGTH - (quantity_positions * threads);

  if (threads == 1)
    for (i = 0; i < quantity_positions; i++){
      if ((vector[i] % 2) == 0)
        sum++;
    }
  else {
    for (i = 1; i < threads; i++){
      pthread_create(&threads_id[i], NULL, VerifyVector, i);

    }

    for(i = 1; i < threads; i++)
      pthread_join(threads_id[i], &threads_result[i]);

    for (i = 1; i < threads; i++)
      sum += threads_result[i];

    for (j = (0 * quantity_positions); j < (quantity_positions + rest); j++)
      if ((vector[j] % 2) == 0)
    sum++;

  }

  printf("The total is: %d\n", sum);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wots with the 'shmget'?  Threads in the same process don't need to make explicit calls to share memory.

Comment: I don't see *any* synchronisation whatsoever. `join` does not synchronise between threads, it only causes the current thread to wait for a specific other thread to finish. Read about mutexes.

Comment: I'm also concerned that you seem to think that array indices start at 1.

Comment: The variable 'j' is global and shared by all the calls to VerifyVector :(

Comment: The local and global vars, both named 'i', is confusing and poor practice, if not actually a bug.

Comment: There's also the issue of your code not compiling unless you go to great lengths to silence the compiler's complaints.

Comment: What @molbdnilo says.  pthread_join() is not magic.  It's not a synchro mechanism for data and often causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: @molbdnilo - I would not even try.  There are too many obvious bugs to bother, even forgetting the non-existent synchro, (which would not matter anyway if the OP did not insist on soddin' globals).

Comment: Can you insert a printf with the computed result whenever you compute something? What do expect from `0 * quantity_positions`?

Comment: I'm not handling this case of 0. The user must enter 1 or more threads. If you compile this code (gcc thread.c -o thread.exe -pthread -w) It is calculating the 500 even numbers... But some times It changes, I don't know why...

Comment: For how many threads have you tried? If the number of threads given is same, does it keep changing the result?

Answer (score 1):

pthread_join() is not magic. It's not a synchro mechanism that you should use to protect data fro multiple access.  It will not do what you seem to think you need.

Furthermore, you don't need synchro anyway since you are not mutating the vector during the run of the threads.

What you DO need is to fix all the bugs as outlined in molbdnilo/my comments.  Stop using confusing i,j,k single-letter vars and don't use global vars unless you really need to.  Fix your array-indexing.

I don't understand all that 'parent process' stuff:(

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Achrome etc. you think that the shared global 'j' is not a cause of the problem?